# WSUS not pushing updates to server 2022 and server 2019

Tags: wsus

Updates show up in WSUS, I can approve them and all of my 2022 & 2019 servers are reporting to WSUS (via: tnc wsusservername -port 8530) but the updates never push to them after I approve them.

I ran server cleanup wizard, did the WUAUCLT commands, and everything else, but they still don't show up.

Have an idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a while back,

go to WSUS console>>Options>>Products and Classifications.

in there scroll down and check the Products you need your WSUS to Pull updates for, and also [these Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYJxZ.jpg)

Comment: Thank. I've always had "21H2" selected and the updates download to WSUS but after I approve them in WSUS, the updates don't push to any servers running 2022 and 2019. I don't see any reason to check 22H2 and 23H2 at this time. Do you mind explaining what your exact issue was?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).